# Modify ControllerContext in CreateController method of DefaultControllerFactory in asp.net core mvc

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, controller-factory

- I want to override my controllers method. Here i have overriden **CreateController** method of **DefaultControllerFactory** to return the **CatalogCustomController** object if request come for **CatalogController**.

But the problem is here that i need to pass all the dependency into controller constructor.

```
 public class CustomControllerFactory: DefaultControllerFactory
{  
    public CustomControllerFactory(ICatalogModelFactory catalogModelFactory,
        IProductModelFactory productModelFactory,
        IControllerActivator controllerActivator, IEnumerable<IControllerPropertyActivator> propertyActivators)
        :base(controllerActivator, propertyActivators)
    {
        this._catalogModelFactory = catalogModelFactory;
        this._productModelFactory = productModelFactory;
    }
    public override object CreateController(ControllerContext context)
    {
        if (context.ActionDescriptor.ControllerTypeInfo.AsType() == typeof(CatalogController))
        {
            return new CatalogCustomController(_catalogModelFactory,
            _productModelFactory,
            _categoryService, 
        }

        return base.CreateController(context);
    }
}
```

While i want to do it something like this, by modifying
   **ControllerContext context**

```
 public override object CreateController(ControllerContext context)
    {
        if (context.ActionDescriptor.ControllerTypeInfo.AsType() == typeof(CatalogController))
        {

            context.ActionDescriptor.ControllerName = "CatalogCustomController";   
        }

        return base.CreateController(context);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try register `Controller` into `IServiceCollection`, and then retrieve `Controller` from `IServiceCollection` in `CreateController`.

1. Extension method for `AddControllersAsServices`

   ```
   public static class Extension
   {
   public static IMvcBuilder AddControllersAsServices(this IMvcBuilder builder)
   {
       var feature = new ControllerFeature();
       builder.PartManager.PopulateFeature(feature);

       foreach (var controller in feature.Controllers.Select(c => c.AsType()))
       {
           builder.Services.TryAddTransient(controller, controller);
       }

       builder.Services.Replace(ServiceDescriptor.Transient<IControllerActivator, ServiceBasedControllerActivator>());

       return builder;
   }
   }
   ```
2. Register Services

   ```
       services.AddMvc()
           .AddControllersAsServices();
   ```
3. `CustomControllerFactory`

   ```
    public class CustomControllerFactory : DefaultControllerFactory
    {
   public CustomControllerFactory(
       IControllerActivator controllerActivator, IEnumerable<IControllerPropertyActivator> propertyActivators)
       : base(controllerActivator, propertyActivators)
   {
   }
   public override object CreateController(ControllerContext context)
   {
       if (context.ActionDescriptor.ControllerTypeInfo.AsType() == typeof(CatalogController))
       {               
           return context.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService(typeof(CatalogCustomController));
       }

       return base.CreateController(context);
   }
   }
   ```

Comment: Thanks for your solution, It is working perfectly as it should.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to do it without registering the controllers as service.

- Inherit the custom controller from main one.
- In custom controller factory, get the type of requested controller.
- Replace the ControllerTypeInfo with the custom one

```
public override object CreateController(ControllerContext context)
    {
        Type typeOfController = context.ActionDescriptor.ControllerTypeInfo.UnderlyingSystemType;
```

`if (typeOfController == typeof(Nop.Web.Controllers.CatalogController))
    {
        context.ActionDescriptor.ControllerTypeInfo = typeof(Controllers.CatalogCustomController).GetTypeInfo();
    }
    else if (typeOfController == typeof(Nop.Web.Areas.Admin.Controllers.ProductController))
    {
        context.ActionDescriptor.ControllerTypeInfo = typeof(Areas.Admin.Controllers.ProductCustomController).GetTypeInfo();
    }
    return base.CreateController(context);  
}<pre>`